# NPE without a stack trace

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jvm, try-catch

I am trying to debug a NPE.

I have used the following flag in Eclipse Run configuration:
`-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`

But I still dont see a stack trace in the NPE. The only line it shows is the line number of the catch statement.

Now this NPE is being thrown from deep inside the call stack and caught somewhere out. So it is a pain and time consuming to go to each inner method and put catch statements or `if (blah==null)` statement.

How can I get a stack trace in Eclipse?

Comment: What version of the JVM? What's the actual error line?  This reminds me and [old java bug](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4292742) that I ran into before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In th Eclipse debugger, you can put a breakpoint on any given type of exception. So, as soon as the NPE will be thrown, your debugger should bring you at the exact location